# PHP SESSION variables to show HTML nav element

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a log-in/register website, and it is all going well, but then when I came to do the nav bar.

EDIT: That works, but the nav bar buttons defined in the PHP code are not clickable.

index.php code

```
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<header>

</header>

<body>

    <nav id="menu">

        <ul id="menu">

            <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/home.html'">Home</li>
            <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/videos.html'">Videos</li>
            <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/news.html'">News</li>

            <?php

                session_start();

                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
                {
                    echo "<li onclick=" . "document.getElementById(" . "content_box" . ").src=" . "pages/accounts/php/user.php" . ">Account</li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li onclick=" . "document.getElementById(" . "content_box" . ").src=" . "pages/accounts/login.html". ">Log In</li>";
                }
            ?>

        </ul>
    </nav>


    <iframe id="content_box" src="pages/home.html" style="border: none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet

```
#blue_dl_button {
    width: 200;
    height: 50;
    background-color: 00cffc;
    color: ffffff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14;
    border-color: 00cffc;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin 0;
    float:left;
}

#green_dl_button {
    width: 200;
    height: 50;
    background-color: 33CC00;
    color: ffffff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14;
    border-color: 33CC00;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin 0;
    float: left;
}

#red_dl_button {
    width: 200;
    height: 50;
    background-color: CC3300;
    color: ffffff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-feature-settings: 
    font-size: 14;
    border-color: CC3300;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin 0;
    float:left
}

#header_image{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

header{
    background-image: url("/header.png");   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 169px 0px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#content_box{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 99.85%;
    height: 100%; 
}

ul#menu{
    background-color: #00C1A7;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

ul#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

ul#menu li:hover{
    background: #00FFE1;
}

#news_title{
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 28;
}

#text{
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18;
}
```

It ends up looking like https://puu.sh/9uVEy/5b39cb95e6.png

[image]

I am stumped as I have looked all over for a solution and could not find one!

Updated code with echo (PHP Bit only)

```
<?php

                    session_start();

                    if($_SESSION['username'])
                    {
                        echo "<li onclick='document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/accounts/php/user.php''>Account</li>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<li onclick='document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/accounts/login.html''>Log In</li>";
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: try to correct it with $_SESSION instead of _$SESSION.

Comment: You need to use either echo, or print, within your if conditions.

Comment: The same happens with echo

Comment: Just a heads up too, that header tag should be inside the body tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` item is in the php tag. You need to either echo it out, or push it out of the php coding. I would do it outside of it, since you use single as well double quotes within it.

Try

```
                <?php
                    session_start();

                    if($_SESSION['username'])
                    {
                ?>
                <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/accounts/php/user.php'">Account</li> 
                <?php 
                    } else {
                ?>
                <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/accounts/login.html'">Log In</li>
                <?php    
                    }
                ?>
```

Also, it's `$_SESSION` not `_$SESSION`. I fixed that too.

Last but not least. Your file extention. You use the index.html file as readout. `HTML` files cant read the php code and won't accept your script within the `<?php ?>` tags. They will read over it, but won't execute it, because HTML won't do server side scriptwork. So in your case, simply change `index.html` to `index.php` and it should work fine.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, it added both nav bars and made it look like this http://puu.sh/9uZNb/b31bc29486.png

Comment: Where is the echo coming from? Cause I didnt add an echo. Can you show your updated code?

Comment: Updated the opening post

Comment: ohhhh wait a minute ... I quote you: `index.html code` : now there is your problem. HTML files can't read PHP. Change the filename to `index.php`. I ll update the awsner from me.

Comment: Changing that worked, but I cannot click the nav bar buttons defined in the PHP part, Updated the OP.

Comment: Its because you have stuff single quoted. It wont work propperly. Remove the echo's and do it like my answer. You ll see, it will work. The echo's aren't handy when you are calling javascript. copy paste my code over, and you ll see it works fine.

Comment: When I do that I get 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\HTML and CSS\WebServer\root\index.php on line 27

Comment: And whats on line 27? You gotta debug a bit. Parse error means mostly that there is a wrongly written syntax, a lost quote or something like that.

Comment: <li onclick="document.getElementById('content_box').src='pages/accounts/php/user.php'">Account</li>;